# LogCat displays Nothing

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't know whether it's Android specific problem or eclipse related problem. My application works fine but after some time LogCat Displays `Aborted LogCat-v Long` and after that doesn't display anything - for me logs are very important - any help ?

```
    06-13 09:48:42.002: INFO/ActivityThread(219): Publishing provider com.android.email.provider: com.android.email.provider.EmailProvider
    06-13 09:48:42.202: INFO/ActivityThread(219): Publishing provider com.android.email.attachmentprovider: com.android.email.provider.AttachmentProvider
    06-13 09:48:42.722: DEBUG/Exchange(219): BootReceiver onReceive
    06-13 09:48:42.871: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(219): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
    06-13 09:48:43.083: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=231 uid=10018 gids={}
    06-13 09:48:43.522: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(219): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
    06-13 09:48:43.632: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Displayed activity com.aqui.mwfa/.Mwfa: 5405 ms (total 34831 ms)
    06-13 09:48:43.651: DEBUG/ddm-heap(231): Got feature list request
    06-13 09:48:43.782: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(219): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
    06-13 09:48:43.883: DEBUG/Eas Debug(219): Logging: 
    06-13 09:48:43.912: DEBUG/EAS SyncManager(219): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
    06-13 09:48:44.503: DEBUG/dalvikvm(102): GC freed 2862 objects / 157944 bytes in 113ms
    06-13 09:48:44.583: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198): opendir /system/media/ failed, errno: 2
    06-13 09:48:44.633: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198):  prescan time: 3125ms
    06-13 09:48:44.642: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198):     scan time: 237ms
    06-13 09:48:44.652: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198): postscan time: 0ms
    06-13 09:48:44.676: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198):    total time: 3362ms
    06-13 09:48:44.702: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(198): done scanning volume internal
    06-13 09:48:44.742: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(198): start scanning volume external
    06-13 09:48:45.031: DEBUG/dalvikvm(52): GREF has increased to 301
    06-13 09:48:45.042: VERBOSE/MediaScanner(198): pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44b75918
    06-13 09:48:45.062: VERBOSE/MediaScanner(198): /pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44b75918
    06-13 09:48:45.093: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198):  prescan time: 250ms
    06-13 09:48:45.113: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198):     scan time: 7ms
    06-13 09:48:45.139: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198): postscan time: 75ms
    06-13 09:48:45.142: DEBUG/MediaScanner(198):    total time: 332ms
    06-13 09:48:45.154: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(198): done scanning volume external
    06-13 09:48:52.001: INFO/ARMAssembler(52): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000A04_00000000 [ 29 ipp] (51 ins) at [0x425130:0x4251fc] in 1355035 ns
    06-13 09:48:52.091: INFO/ARMAssembler(52): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001A01_00000000 [ 73 ipp] (98 ins) at [0x4965a0:0x496728] in 923700 ns
    06-13 09:48:52.241: INFO/ARMAssembler(52): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x4951c0:0x49527c] in 529085 ns
    06-13 09:48:53.852: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Killing process com.android.mms (pid=147) at user's request
    06-13 09:48:53.861: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 147 SIG: 9
    06-13 09:48:53.901: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Process com.android.mms (pid 147) has died.
    06-13 09:48:54.052: INFO/ARMAssembler(52): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x495280:0x495448] in 1167970 ns
    06-13 09:48:54.061: ERROR/gralloc(52): [unregister] handle 0x43d970 still locked (state=40000001)
    06-13 09:48:56.491: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.aqui.mwfa/.Sfa }
    06-13 09:48:57.332: DEBUG/dalvikvm(210): GC freed 3003 objects / 224688 bytes in 401ms
    06-13 09:48:57.513: DEBUG/request data(210): http://www.aquilonis.net:6789/Aqui-MWFA_p2/mobile:type=getcustomer, uid=49, 
    06-13 09:48:58.412: DEBUG/response data::(210): true#@@#1#@#Abhay Traders#@#3,4#@@#2#@#Abu Traders#@#3,4#@@#3#@#Dhamtari Sales#@#3,4#@@#4#@#Ganesh Traders#@#3,4#@@#5#@#Ganga Sales#@#3,4#@@#6#@#Jyoti Traders#@#3,4#@@#7#@#Krishi Traders#@#3,4#@@#8#@#Manoj Traders#@#3,4
    06-13 09:48:58.412: DEBUG/response data::(210): [ 06-13 09:48:58.412   210:0xd2 D/true#@@#1#@#Abhay Traders#@#3,4#@@#2#@#Abu Traders#@#3,4#@@#3#@#Dhamtari Sales#@#3,4#@@#4#@#G
06-13 09:48:59.291: 
DEBUG/response data::(210): true#@@#1#@#Abhay [1]   Aborted                 logcat -v long
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If this is happening in Eclipse then you will need to close Eclipse and restart it: every so often the ADT in Eclipse loses the connection to the logcat process that it uses to display the logs.

If this is happening at the command line then you might have a driver issue: I'd suggest reinstalling the necessary drivers.

Comment: i restarted it lot many times.. but same problem occurs every time.. any way i'll try the second one now n check....

Comment: If you run `logcat` at a command line or shell do you get any output?

Comment: i Did't bother to go there.. I always use LogCat of eclipse IDE.. so not sure how to check them in command line or shell

Comment: Well, now may be a good time to try it out at the command line and help you figure out where the problem is: if you open up a command line (I'm assuming you are on Windows: use Start->Run and then type *cmd*) and then type `adb logcat` what does it say?

Comment: wow... ya i got.. thanks.. let me see wat it says..

Comment: any way thanx.. atleast i got an alternative...

Comment: Sure. Eclipse REALLY should recover though, so if it persists you may have another issue to look at.

Comment: If you use a real device, you can try to unplug and plug the usb cable again. Eclipse will tell something like "device not found (-1)". Next time you start your app, logcat should be displayed. At least it solved my issue...

Answer (score 3):

A lot of times, the device/emulator whose logs you want to see is not selected in DDMS. Just clicking on it loads the logs in LogCat. I used to get frustrated due to the same problem until I stumbled upon this.

Comment: ya i know it.. but problem is not exactly tat.. its something else.. thnx for the answer any ways..